# nodejs impersonation with windows

Tags: windows, node.js, filesystems, impersonation

I need to use nodejs to write file to a password protected shared folder on a remote machine running Windows server 2008 r2, how can I do impersonation things within nodejs like .net app does?

Thx in advance!!!

**PS:
Sorry for the unclear description. The folder is set to shared across the internal network on the remote windows server system, the folder is set to "readonly" for the windows account explicitly created by the admin. The nodejs server is on the same internal network and need to access the remote shared folder, thus I think nodejs need to impersonate the windows account on the remote machine to read contents from the shared folder. My question is how to do the sorry for the unclear description. The folder is set to shared across the internal network on the remote windows server system, the folder is set to "readonly" for the windows account explicitly created by the admin. The nodejs server is on the same internal network and need to access the remote shared folder, thus I think nodejs need to impersonate the windows account on the remote machine to read contents from the shared folder. My question is how to do the impersonation stuff for nodejs?**

Comment: Do you need to impersonate, or do you just need to access the file share using explicit credentials?  And is it a firm requirement to use node.js?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description, I have edited the question hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party - but since there is no accepted answer...

You'll need to launch your node process using the account that has access to the network share. How this is done differs based on your setup. For example, if you're runnning node on a lLinux server trying to connect to the remote Windows server, then it's not going to be straightforward with node.

However; if you're running node on a Windows server, trying to connect to a remote share on another Windows server (which is what it sounds like your situation probably is). Again, you'll have to run your node script as a user with access to the remote share. If you need to do it from code, I'd suggest taking a look at my module [node-windows](http://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows). It doesn't provide remote share access specifically, but it will allow you to run command line code with a different account from within your node script.